# How to arrange much information on less space

Tags: website-design, design

I'm having much factual information, which has to be arranged on a plenty small space. Do you have some hints, perhaps design studies, how to present these information efficiently?

To have something to work with, imagine a page introducing a person: You have some short information like name, birth date, birth place and size. Of course there is a picture of the person as well.
Additionally there is a short excerpt of his/her life before there is a deep-dive into the persons recent works. At the End, there are some links to sites selling the work of the person.
Imagine, the person is an artist, then there are some photos of the persons arts. At last, the person has written an own text with some thoughts of him or herself and the work.

Displaying all these information from top to down results in a long site, no one will ever read this. So I need some inspiration, how to separate these information. One approach would be a tabbed view, but there is more than this, I'm sure.

So, do you have examples?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought you were asking something only suited for stackoverflow.com but since this is a forum for webmasters, part of your question allows me to give an answer.

**Go for pagination and use categories**.

Trying to put a ton of items all on one page of the site can be a disaster especially when the number of items are in the thousands or more.

If the items cannot be categorized, then divide them all up into pages, where each page (ideally) cannot have more than 100 items. Add a navigational section to each page.

For example, if you have 500 items, then make the first page have 100 items with a link to the next page which contains the next 100 items and on that page, make a link to the third set of 100 items. Keep doing that until you get to the last set of 100 items. Also, work on the previous page options to make things user friendly.

Here's a trick to make pagination easy:

First determine how many items you intend to list.

Second, divide that number by the number of items you want per page. Try to make this number a maximum of 100

Next, take the result and if it is greater than two, then for all the pages labeled with a number between 1 and the last number, use both navigational options to allow the user to switch between the previous and next page.

For the first page, use only one navigational option pointing to the next page.

For the last page, use only one navigational option pointing to the previous page.

If you can sort the items by category, then you should paginate each category. For example, if you had 1000 different flavors of coffee, and 500 rocks you want to present, then you can have a section on your site asking the user to choose either coffee or rocks, then on each page, you can create a pagination scheme as defined above for each item. Then in your title tag, it will show something like "Coffee items page 1", "coffee items page 2", etc. when coffee is chosen and people are browsing it. A similar effect works with rocks. Those pages can be titled "Rocks page 1", "Rocks page 2", etc.

Pagination is the standard way to solve your problem based on the title of your question. Even this site uses pagination when you browse questions.